# Fast server-side language or framework

Tags: language, server

I need to elaborate the global language stack of my website, especially on the server side.

On each final user's request, the website has to perform some math computing (algorithm) on the server side (involving external API requests, and calculations based on their results).

For this purpose, I'm looking for a language / framework which is:

- server-side
- as fast as possible
- modern, possibly designed to be "scalable" (I put it inside quotes because I'm new with this concept)
- widely offered in the present commercial hosting solutions

For test purposes, the first version of the algorithm is written in Php. But it runs to slowly (I'm talking about the script execution, not about my own code optimizations).

I'm thinking about Java, or Node.js, or even maybe a C++ program compiled for the right platform... But I don't know which solution is the most commonly used nowadays. I'm not asking about THE best solution (which is too subjective), but about a list of possible ways to explore...

Comment: C/C++ is probably the fastest, but it isn't commonly used...

Comment: Asp.net can do this well